# ROS wiki password reset broken?

Tags: ros, ros2, wiki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I use the [Lost Password page](http://wiki.ros.org/action/recoverpass/Documentation?action=recoverpass) and enter my username and email, I get an error "`{u'<redacted@example.com>': (450, '4.1.8 <moin@ros.osuosl.org>: Sender address rejected: Domain not found')}`" (redaction my own).

How do I reset my password?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/358318/ros-wiki-password-reset-broken?/) by [DanRose](https://answers.ros.org/users/43942/danrose/) on ROS Answers with karma: 274 on 2020-07-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kscottz](https://answers.ros.org/users/13336/kscottz/) on 2020-07-30**:
Strange, we've been having some issues lately with the wiki. Can you PM your e-mail address so we can take a look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The from address of the server was [misconfigured](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/roswiki/pull/315). It should be able to send the emails now.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2020-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0